# error when i run nodejs on EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

After I git clone my app onto EC2 and run it with the following command:

```
nohup nodejs app.js &
```

I get the following error:

```
[Error: /home/ubuntu/bluesky-scheduler2/node_modules/agenda/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/build/Release/bson.node: invalid ELF header]
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
[Error: /home/ubuntu/bluesky-scheduler2/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/build/Release/bson.node: invalid ELF header]
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

Any ideas how can I fix this?

Comment: How did you install the node_modules. It appears that the mongo driver is trying to load a file that is not linux native

Comment: i installed them using npc install on my local machine, then i git push to my repo and then cloned my repo onto the EC2 server

Comment: You may need to set the node_modules directory to ignore, and instead install them on the server. It would appear that a binary file installed for your local machine is not compatible with your server environment.

Comment: You have to do npm install on the instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. The invalid ELF header implies a binary that is not loadable or executable by the system. So I tried to build bson.

go to the root directory of the bson module.
e.g. in my case: `mongodb/node_modules/bson`
and then execute `make`

tldr;

```
$ cd /home/ubuntu/bluesky-scheduler2/node_modules/agenda/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/
$ make
```

Comment: Unrelated but I'll suggest using PM2 for running your node app in production: [PM2 Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I inadvertently committed the `node_modules/mongodb` folder in git after developing on a windows box.  Most node modules will be generic javascript an run on either windows or linux, however mongodb has binary files specific to the operating system in the `node_modules/mongodb` folder.  Deploying the code to linux pushes a windows binary to linux, hence the error.

The solution is to remove the `nodemodules/mongodb` directory on the linux server, then run `npm install` to install mongodb dependancies from the linux environment.